# DrawImage Out of Memory

Tags: c#, memory, drawimage

My program keeps throwing this dang error, I have absolutely no idea why. I have searched the internet but so far there i haven't found any real answer to it. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
    private Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap b, float angle)
    {
        //create a new empty bitmap to hold rotated image
        Bitmap returnBitmap = new Bitmap(b.Width, b.Height,System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        //make a graphics object from the empty bitmap
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap);
        //move rotation point to center of image
        g.TranslateTransform((float)b.Width / 2, (float)b.Height / 2);
        //rotate
        g.RotateTransform((int)angle);
        //move image back
        g.TranslateTransform(-(float)b.Width / 2, -(float)b.Height / 2);
        //draw passed in image onto graphics object
        b = (Bitmap)b.GetThumbnailImage(b.Width, b.Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
        g.DrawImage(b, new Point(0, 0)); // Here is the error.
        b.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
        return returnBitmap;
    }
```

Edit: The error is: "Out of memory" and it appears aprox. 10 seconds after running the program. Before this, the program runs perfectly.

Comment: Can you post the specific error text?

Comment: On which line the error is thrown?

Comment: I marked the error with a comment, line 15, right above the dispose ones. The error is a simple "Out of Memory".

Comment: And how often to you call this method? And how large is the bitmap you're rotating?

Comment: It's relatively small, definitely not a reasonable reason for the error

Comment: Is the code that calls this method disposing the `returnBitmap` after you're done using it? Does the error occur the first time you call this method, or after calling it multiple times?

Comment: Well, I've tried disposing it at the end of the method, same result. Oh and the program works fine for aprox. 10 seconds, then it pops the error, so it's not the first time I call it.

Comment: I'd be more suspicious of the code that calls this method. Do you have something like `var bmp = rotateImage(...); /* other stuff */ bmp.Dispose();` If you don't dispose of the bitmap after you're done using it, you can very easily run out of memory.

Comment: This is my code: pictureBox_Shotgun.Image = rotateImage((Bitmap)image, angle); Doesn't it replace the image automatically?

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft docs for `Image.GetThumbnailImage` it states:

> callback
>
> Type: System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort
>
> A Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort delegate.
>
> Note   You must create a delegate and pass a reference to the delegate
>   as the callback parameter, but the delegate is not used.

Maybe you should add that delegate.

```
Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort abortCallback =
    new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(() => false);
b = (Bitmap)b.GetThumbnailImage(b.Width, b.Height, abortCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Comment: Can you please post a small snippet of code showing how you create/refference a delegate as the "callback parameter". I'm fairly new to C# and I feel I can learn more from example. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this could help but can you try this code and report if error is still there?

```
private Bitmap rotateImage(Bitmap b, float angle)
{
    using (var returnBitmap = new Bitmap(b.Width, b.Height,System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb))
    {
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(returnBitmap))
        {
            g.TranslateTransform((float)b.Width / 2, (float)b.Height / 2);
            g.RotateTransform((int)angle);
            g.TranslateTransform(-(float)b.Width / 2, -(float)b.Height / 2);
            b = (Bitmap)b.GetThumbnailImage(b.Width, b.Height, null, IntPtr.Zero);
            g.DrawImage(b, new Point(0, 0)); // Is the error still present?
            return returnBitmap;
        }
    }
}
```